# Parameter passing in Oauth1 - google API

Tags: python, authentication, oauth, google-contacts-api

I have authenticated the the user with scope of Google mail and Google contacts using Oauth1. Fetching mail is working perfectly fine with imaplib

While calling contacts API I'm getting the responds but when I make parametrized call i'm getting an error like "Authorization required"

eg:The user is authenticated for the API(scope) " https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full" and I like to get responds it in json format so the API will look like " https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?alt=json " -- this API will give me error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have identified the problem:

The problem was I was not including the parameters of the URL before generating signature for oAuth 1.0